# Eclipse IDE transcript of execution

Tags: eclipse

Has any got any idea if it is possible to obtain the transcript of program execution output from the eclipse terminal?

Comment: The "transcript of program execution?"  Do you mean a stack trace, or are you trying to redirect stdout?

Comment: redirect output so I can use the output

Comment: http://www.mathinfo.u-picardie.fr/asch/f/MeCS/courseware/users/help/general/unix/redirection.html

Comment: You should be able to get what you want by doing an Internet search on *redirecting stdout, pipes,* and your *operating system* of choice.